Locally uniformly convexity in kernels (generalized definition of graphon) with cut norm
Let $\mathcal{W}$ denote the space of all bounded symmetric measurable functions
$W : [0, 1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$ For any $W\in\mathcal{W}$ we say it is a kernel and define its cut norm $\lVert W\rVert_\square=\sup\limits_{S,T\subseteq [0,1]}\Big|\int\limits_{S\times T}W(x,y)\,dx\,dy\Big|.$ For any two kernels $W_1,W_2$, we say it is isomorphism if there exists two $1$-$1$ maps $f_1,f_2:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $W_1(x,y)=W_2(f_1(x),f_2(y))$.
Let $0<p<1$ and $\varepsilon$ be a positive constant independent with $p$. In which condition does the following hold for a kernel $W$ with $\int W=0$ and $\lVert W\rVert_\square=p$?:
There exists $W'$ isomorphism with $W$ such that $\lVert W+W'\rVert_\square\leq p^{1+\varepsilon}.$
Remark: There is a trivial bound $\lVert W+W'\rVert_\square\leq O(p).$ It is wrong to let this hold for every $W$ satisfying the condition, so for which special kind of $W$ it holds? For example, if the homomorphism number of even cycle satisfied $t(C_{2k},W)\leq O((\int W)^{c(\varepsilon)2k})$ for constant $c=c(\varepsilon)$, could it hold?
